# Filter result from Store

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I am loading values from a Store, and then filtering it with a condition (for example  `name == Matt`). The code is shown below;

```
var store = Ext.getStore('mystore');
store.on('load', function() {
    store.filter({
        filterFn: function(rec) {
            return Ext.Array.indexOf(arr, rec.get('name')) > -1;
        }
    });
});
     store.load();
```

Later on, in another view, i need to use the filtered result (shown above) and filter it against another array of values. How can i do this;

My approach was to load the records again (Paste the above code again - but without the filter part of it). But this is incorrect. So how can i Filter results from the previously filtered result array ?

Answer (score 3):

You can define filters to run on store load in its `filters` property and setting `filterOnLoad` property to `true`.

To filter records against new filter conditions:

```
store.clearFilter(true); // Clears old filters
store.filter([
    {
         filterFn: function(rec) {
              return Ext.Array.indexOf(arr, rec.get('name')) > -1;
         }
    }
]);
```

Comment: What hapence if i want to compare it against an Array, as shown in my code. Your code works, but for a single value, Could you help me to compare it against an Array of values ?

Comment: I would like to filter it before filtering it for the 2nd time. Which you did before `{property:"email", value: /\.com$/},`

Comment: Don't undestand your last comment.